# Microsoft Access to SQL Error - "Could not find stored procedure 'test;1"

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, stored-procedures

I have a Microsoft Access front-end (ADP Project) in Access 2010.  It hits a SQL Server 2012 backend database.

After updating from an older version of SQL Server, I now have a weird problem where all of the stored procedures listed in the front-end have a ;1 appended to their name.  When I click on them, I get the following error in Access.

"Could not find stored procedure name;1" (where name is the name of the stored procedure)

All of these work fine in in the SQL Server manager software.  I'm using the same user account in the Access front-end, and in the SQL Server backend.

Any ideas? I tried looking online, but couldn't find the same problem anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad news.

It looks like [Access 2010 ADPs can't use SQL Server 2012 as a backend](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/02508f4f-0436-44ef-acd7-86db9c0b3826/is-access-adp-compatible-with-sql-sever-2012).  Worse, [ADPs were discontinued after Access 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj618413.aspx).  You'd have to convert to the new system.

Relevant portion (emphasis mine):

> ADPs continue to work in earlier versions of Access. You can continue to develop your ADP applications and we will continue to support earlier versions of Access under the standard support lifecycle. **We will not update older versions of Access to support new versions of SQL Server or SQL Azure. Therefore, you may encounter issues if you use SQL Server 2012 or later versions with your ADP. ADPs will continue to support SQL 2008 R2 and earlier.**

Comment: Bummer...  I heard about the adp issue, but hadn't seen that the stored procedures wouldn't work either.  Thanks for the help - it's much appreciated.